# Сохранить переменную webview в андроид

Tags: javascript, java, android

Есть переменная

```
localStorage.id=$(this).attr("id");
```

в зависимости от этой переменной формируется позиция,с которой выведется список.
Подскажите как мне при выходе из приложения сохранить этот `id` на устройстве, а затем при повторном запуске,взять эту переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать запись в БД SQLite (уже есть на устройстве).
"SQLite доступен на любом Android-устройстве, его не нужно устанавливать отдельно."
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php

При запуске приложения - просто проверяйте наличие записей в БД и если они есть - обновляйте состояние приложения.

Каждое изменение состояния (важное) можете сохранять в БД.

Comment: А как получить переменную из webview,а затем обратно?

Comment: Если переменная хранится в javascript-переменной на странице, то нужно воспользоваться прослойкой между Андройдом и WebView javascript'ом: JavaScriptInterface. Подробнее в документации (https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) и вот тут: http://www.darkraha.com/rus/mobile/android/gui/view_webview/javascript.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview